# How to predict multiple images in Keras at a time using multiple-processing (e.g. with different CPUs)?

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing, conv-neural-network, prediction

I have a lot of PNG images that I want to classify, using a trained CNN model.

To speed up the process, I would like to use multiple-processing with CPUs (I have 72 available, here I'm just using 4). I don't have a GPU available at the moment, but if necessary, I could get one.

**My workflow:**

1. read a figure with `openCV`
2. adapt shape and format
3. use `mymodel.predict(img)` to get the probability for each class

When it comes to the prediction step, it never finishes the `mymodel.predict(img)` step. When I use the code without the multiprocessing module, it works fine. For the model, I'm using keras with a tensorflow backend.

```
# load model
mymodel = load_model('190704_1_fcs_plotclassifier.h5')

# use python library multiprocessing to use different CPUs
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(4)

# Define callback function to collect the output in 'outcomes'
outcomes = []

def collect_result(result):
    global outcomes
    outcomes.append(result)

# Define prediction function

def prediction(img):
    img = cv2.resize(img,(49,49))
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255
    img = np.reshape(img,[1,49,49,3])       

    status = mymodel.predict(img)
    status = status[0][1]

    return(status)

# Define evaluate function

def evaluate(i,figure):

    # predict the propability of the picture to be in class 0 or 1
    img = cv2.imread(figure)
    status = prediction(img)

    outcome = [figure, status]
    return(i,outcome)

# execute multiprocessing
for i, item in enumerate(listoffigurepaths):
        pool.apply_async(evaluate, args=(i, item), callback=collect_result)
pool.close()
pool.join()

# get outcome
print(outcomes)
```

It would be great if somebody knows how to predict several images at a time!

I simplified my code here, but if somebody has an example how it could be done, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

### Does a processing-speed 
or a size-of-RAM
or a number-of-CPU-cores
or an introduced add-on processing latency matter most?
[ALL OF THESE DO:](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

The python **`multiprocessing`** module is known ( and the **`joblib`** does the same ) to:

> The `multiprocessing` package offers both local and remote concurrency, **effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock** by using **subprocesses** instead of threads.

Yet, as everything in our Universe, this comes at cost:

The wish, expressed by O/P as:

> *To speed up the process, I would like to **use multiple-processing with CPUs** (I have **72 available***

will, for this kind of a similar application of a pre-trained **`mymodel.predict()`**-or, if sent into a `Pool( 72 )`-execution almost for sure suffocate almost any hardware RAM by swapping.

Here is an example, where "just"-Do-Nothing worker was spawned by the **`n_jobs = 100`** directive - to see what happens ( time-wise ~ 532+ [ms] lost + memory-allocation-wise where XYZ [GB] or RAM have immediately been allocated by O/S ):

[image]

This comes from the fact, that each **`multiprocessing`** spawned sub-process ( not threads, as O/P has already experienced on her own ) is first instantiated ( after an adequate add-on latency due to O/S process/RAM-allocations-management ) as a ---**FULL-COPY**--- of the ecosystem present inside the original python process ( the complete **`python`** interpreter + all its **`import`**-ed modules + all its internal state and data-structures - used or not - ) so indeed huge amounts of RAM-allocations take place ( have you noticed the platform started to SWAP? notice how many sub-processes were spawned until that time and you have a ceiling of how many such can fit in-RAM and it makes devastating performance effects if trying ( or letting, by using the **`joblib`**-s `n_jobs = -1` auto-scaling directive ) to populate more sub-processes, that this SWAP-introducing number...

So far good, we have paid some ( often for carefully designed code a reasonably negligible amount, if compared to fully train again the whole predictor, doesn't it? ) time to spawn some number of parallel processes.

If the distributed workload next goes back, to one, common and performance-wise singular resource ( a disk directory-tree with files ), the performance of parallel-processes goes but in wreck havoc - it has to wait for such resource(!) to first get it free again.

Finally, even the "right"-amount of **`Pool()`**-spawned sub-processes, such that prevents am O/S to start SWAPPING RAM to disk and back, the inter-process communication is extremely expensive -- here, serialising ( Pickling/unPickling ) + enQueueing + deQueueing all DATA-objects, one has to pass there and back ( yes, even for the **`callback`** fun ), so the less one sends, the way faster the `Pool`-processing will become.

Here, all `Pool`-associated processes might benefit from independent logging of the results, which may reduce both the scales and latency of the inter-process communications, but will also consolidate the results, reported by any number of workers into the common log.

---

### How to ... ? First benchmark the costs of each step:

Without hard facts ( measured durations in `[us]` ), one remains with just an opinion.

```
def prediction( img ):
    img = cv2.resize( img, ( 49, 49 ) ) 
    img = img.astype( 'float32' ) / 255
    img = np.reshape( img, [1, 49, 49, 3] )       

    status = mymodel.predict( img )
    status = status[0][1]

    return( status )

def evaluate( i, figure ):  # predict the propability of the picture to be in class 0 or 1
    img = cv2.imread( figure )
    status = prediction( img )

    outcome = [figure, status]

    return( i, outcome )
#--------------------------------------------------
from zmq import Stopwatch
aClk = Stopwatch()
#------------------------------------NOW THE COSTS OF ORIGINAL VERSION:
aListOfRESULTs = []
for iii in range( 100 ):
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    aClk.start(); _ = evaluate( 1, aFigureNAME ); A = aClk.stop()
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    print( "as-is took {0:}[us]".format( A ) );aListOfRESULTs.append( A )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
print( [ aFun( aListOfRESULTs ) for aFun in ( np.min, np.mean, np.max ) ] )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Lets try something a bit else:

```
def eval_w_RAM_allocs_avoided( indexI, aFigureNAME ):
    return [ indexI,
             [ aFigureNAME,
               mymodel.predict( ( cv2.resize( cv2.imread( aFigureNAME ),
                                              ( 49, 49 )
                                              ).astype( 'float32' ) / 255
                                  ).reshape( [1, 49, 49, 3]
                                             )
                                )[0][1],
               ],
             ]

#------------------------------------NOW THE COSTS OF MOD-ed VERSION:
aListOfRESULTs = []
for iii in range( 100 ):
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    aClk.start()
    _ = eval_w_RAM_allocs_avoided( 1, aFigureNAME )
    B = aClk.stop()
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    print( "MOD-ed took {0:}[us] ~ {1:} x".format( B, float( B ) / A ) )
    aListOfRESULTs.append( B )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
print( [ aFun( aListOfRESULTs ) for aFun in ( np.min, np.mean, np.max ) ] )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

And the actual `img` pre-processing pipeline overhead costs:

```
#------------------------------------NOW THE COSTS OF THE IMG-PREPROCESSING
aListOfRESULTs = []
for iii in range( 100 ):
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    aClk.start()
    aPredictorSpecificFormatIMAGE = ( cv2.resize( cv2.imread( aFigureNAME ),
                                                  ( 49, 49 )
                                                  ).astype( 'float32' ) / 255
                                      ).reshape( [1, 49, 49, 3]
                                                 )
    C = aClk.stop()
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    print( "IMG setup took {0:}[us] ~ {1:} of A".format( C, float( C ) / A ) )
    aListOfRESULTs.append( C )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
print( [ aFun( aListOfRESULTs ) for aFun in ( np.min, np.mean, np.max ) ] )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Actual fileI/O ops:

```
#------------------------------------NOW THE COSTS OF THE IMG-FILE-I/O-READ
aListOfRESULTs = []
for iii in range( 100 ):
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    aFileNAME = listoffigurepaths[158 + iii * 172]
    aClk.start()
    _ = cv2.imread( aFileNAME )
    F = aClk.stop()
    #-------------------------------------------------aClk-ed---------- SECTION
    print( "aFileIO took {0:}[us] ~ {1:} of A".format( F, float( F ) / A ) )
    aListOfRESULTs.append( F )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
print( [ aFun( aListOfRESULTs ) for aFun in ( np.min, np.mean, np.max ) ] )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Without these hard-fact collected ( as a form of quantitative records-of-evidence ), one could hardly decide, what would be the best performance boosting step here for any massive-scale prediction-pipeline image processing.

Having these items tested, post results and further steps ( be it for going via **`multiprocessing.Pool`** or using other strategy for larger performance scaling, to whatever higher performance ) may first get reasonably evaluated, as the hard facts were first collected to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One python package I know that may help you is `joblib`. Hope it can solve your problem.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

```
# load model
mymodel = load_model('190704_1_fcs_plotclassifier.h5')

# Define callback function to collect the output in 'outcomes'
outcomes = []

def collect_result(result):
    global outcomes
    outcomes.append(result)

# Define prediction function

def prediction(img):
    img = cv2.resize(img,(49,49))
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255
    img = np.reshape(img,[1,49,49,3])       

    status = mymodel.predict(img)
    status = status[0][1]

    return(status)

# Define evaluate function

def evaluate(i,figure):

    # predict the propability of the picture to be in class 0 or 1
    img = cv2.imread(figure)
    status = prediction(img)

    outcome = [figure, status]
    return(i,outcome)

outcomes = Parallel(n_jobs=72)(delayed(evaluate)(i,figure) for figure in listoffigurepaths)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to progress a bit:
I had to add this to my model prediction:

    `mymodel = load_model('190704_1_fcs_plotclassifier.h5');
    mymodel._make_predict_function();
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()`

this to my prediction function:
    `with graph.as_default():
        status = mymodel.predict(img)`

And then it only worked with the use of threads:
    `outcomes = Parallel(n_jobs=10, prefer="threads")(delayed(evaluate)(figure) for figure in listoffigurepaths)`

Comment: With all due respect, the **proposed `joblib`** uses the very same package - the **`multiprocessing`** module as one of its possible backends, so no, this will not solve the O/P indicated performance problems ( neither does the threading, as it leaves any-number-of-python-threads inside a common jail of the performance blocking of the **global GIL-lock-trap.**

Answer (score -1):

img_height = 512 # Height of the input images

img_width =512 # Width of the input images

img_channels = 3 # Number of color channels of the input images

orig_images = [] # Store the images here.

batch_holder = np.zeros((20, img_height, img_width, 3))

img_dir =  "path/to/image/"

for i,img, in enumerate(os.listdir(img_dir)):

img = os.path.join(img_dir, img)

orig_images.append(imread(img))

img =image.load_img(img, target_size=(img_height, img_width))

batch_holder[i,:] =img

y_pred = model.predict(batch_holder)

y_pred_decoded = decode_y(y_pred,parameter)

np.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True, linewidth=90)

print("Predicted boxes:\n")

print('    class    conf  xmin     ymin   xmax    ymax')

print(y_pred_decoded[i])

## Display the image and draw the predicted boxes onto it.

## Set the colors for the bounding boxes

colors = plt.cm.hsv(np.linspace(0, 1, 21)).tolist()

classes = ['background','class']

current_axis = plt.gca()

for box in y_pred_decoded[I]:

xmin = box[-4] * orig_images[0].shape[1] / img_width

ymin = box[-3] * orig_images[0].shape[0] / img_height

xmax = box[-2] * orig_images[0].shape[1] / img_width

ymax = box[-1] * orig_images[0].shape[0] / img_height

color = colors[int(box[0])]

label = '{}: {:.2f}'.format(classes[int(box[0])], box[1])

current_axis.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((xmin, ymin), xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin,

color=color, fill=False, linewidth=2))

current_axis.text(xmin, ymin, label, size='x-large', color='white',

bbox={'facecolor': color, 'alpha': 1.0})

plt.imshow(orig_images[i])

plt.show()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).